# Do I have to deploy Qt libraries together with my package?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm developing a program which uses Qt and is supposed to run on Ubuntu, Debian, CentOS and Fedora.

As I understand each of enumerated Linux distributives has it's own Qt libraries, supplied as well.

But project I'm working on uses customly built Qt libraries to build and deploy.

Is it so necessary?

What pitfalls can arise if I make it use system Qt libraries?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to place Qt binaries along side your executable since your app is compiled against a specific version of Qt with specific tool-chain. Also there is no guarantee that the destination Linux distribution has Qt library of the same version compiled with the same tool-chain.

If you don't ship all dependent libraries then your app may not run on some systems.

You should place Qt .so files along the release version of your executable. These are libQtCore.so, libQtGui.so and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These so files are in your installed Qt directory in lib folder or in directory "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu". If you are using plugins you should place their so files in a folder named "plugins" beside your binary. In case of using icons and images you should ship their so files like libqico.so and libqsvg.so in a folder named "imageformats".

Comment: Should probably note two things: if you PAY for QT and get the non LGPL, you can get around this by statically linking to QT. If you don't, then you NEED to show the LGPL when you redistribute QT.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams LGPL is fine for static linking. Your customer needs to be able to relink your closed-source objects, but that's rather simple to deal with. The "show the LGPL" phrase is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is mostly meant to give you a starting point, or encouragement to try it out.

You should build against the lowest Qt version that you can. Qt promises downwards binary compatibility in the libraries (assuming they're configured in a compatible way, and are using compatible compiler and other libraries).

Note that you may also run into problems with versions of other libraries, such as C standard library. So not only should you use an old Qt, you should also build on an older version of a Linux distro.

Once you do these, the same application binary has a high chance of working on different Linux distributions, and different versions of same distribution. Still, test with all distros you want to support!

---

Still, at this day and age of virtual machines, you should really set up a virtual machine for each supported distro and compile a custom package. A server version with no GUI running, just dev packages, should need only a few gigs of disk space (with dynamic virtual disk), and need less than a gig of "extra" memory per running VM to run well. You can set up something like Jenkins slave on each of them, or just use something like ssh to run build scripts in each VM.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to test on several distros. But is it okay if I link against lowest customly built qt libs but rely upon qt libs supplied with the system?

Comment: @kopalvich It may be ok for some combinations. If the application launches on some distro, it is *probably* ok for that distro.